# The dictionary passes me the wrong key’s value

Tags: python, aiogram

I'm developing telegram bot. My bot helps users to remember their things to do. So the thing is there are many types of such things to do which user can create: everyday, every week, few times a day, once a year, etc. My bot has a command which shows user's records. To do it properly I wrote a function which makes text of the answer (e.g. if type is "everyday" then bot answers "everyday at HH:MM", if type is "every week" then bot says "every monday at HH:MM").
My problem is that to do it I made a dictionary where keys are types of such records, values are text which bot might tell user. But this dictionary doesn't work correct: when I pass record type "month" or "everyday" or any other to the function it always get value of key "week" although it should get value of key "month" or "everyday". I get KeyError besause of it

Code:
Main function with the command to show records:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['reminders'], state="*")
async def show_reminder(message: types.Message):
    """
    Shows user's records
    """
    records = get_records(int(message.from_user.id))
    if records:
        await message.answer(messages.show_records_message)
        for item in records:
            await message.answer(make_record_text(item))
    else:
        ###
```

The function which creates text of the answer:

```
def make_record_text(record: Record) -> str:
    """
    Creates an answer with user's record using Record
    """
    days_of_week_dict = {
        'monday': "every monday",
        'tuesday': "every tuesday",
        'wednesday': "every wednesday",
        'thursday': "every thursday",
        'friday': "every friday",
        'saturday': "every saturday",
        'sunday': "every sunday",
    }
    print(f'record = {record}')
    print(f'record type = {record.type}')
    print(f'record date = {record.date}')
    print(f'record time = {record.time}')

    periods = {'year': f'every year {record.time}',
               'once': record.date,
               'week': f'{days_of_week_dict[record.time]}',
               'month': f'every month on {record.time}',
               'several_min': f'every {record.time} minutes',
               'everyday': f'everyday at {record.time}',
               'several_hours': f'every {record.time} hours',
               'every_few_days': f'every {record.time} days',
               }

    return messages.list_records_message.format(title=record.title,
                                                date=periods[record.type],
                                                id=record.id)
```

output:

```
record = Record(user=1234, title='month', date='month', time='25', type='month', need_delete=0, id=1)
record type = month
record date = month
record time = 25
```

Class Record:

```
class Record(NamedTuple):
    user: int
    title: str
    date: Union[type(datetime.datetime), str]
    time: Union[type(datetime.datetime), str]
    type: Literal['everyday', 'few_times_a_day', 'every_few_days',
                  'week', 'month', 'year', 'once']
    need_delete: bool
    id: Optional[int]
```

Error message:

```
File "C:\Users\pizhlo21\Desktop\Folder\python\tg_bot_reminder\controller.py", line 121, in show_reminder
    await message.answer(make_record_text(item))
  File "C:\Users\pizhlo21\Desktop\Folder\python\tg_bot_reminder\controller.py", line 146, in make_record_text
    'week': f'{days_of_week_dict[record.time]}',
KeyError: '25'
```

Why does it happen if I pass "month"?

Comment: Based on the error message, `record.time` is the string `"25"`, and that's certainly not one of the keys in `days_of_week_dict`. What were you expecting to happen..?

Comment: Ah, now I see what's happening – `periods` is being evaluated for all choices regardless of what the type is. That's answerable, just a sec!

Comment: @AKX I expected that it returns `periods['month']`, not `periods['week']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're building the whole `periods` dict before knowing whether the `record.time` value is valid for that kind of period, and evaluating `f'{days_of_week_dict[record.time]}'` has Python try and access `days_of_week_dict["25"]`, which isn't going to fly.

I switched your `namedtuple` for a `dataclass` below since it feels more accurate, but the actual fix is the `match` statement that only formats the human-readable period that's appropriate for the `type`. (If your [Python version is older than 3.10](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#pep-634-structural-pattern-matching) and doesn't have `match`, you can replace it with `if self.type == "year"`, etc.)

```
import dataclasses
import datetime
from typing import Union, Literal, Optional

days_of_week_dict = {
    "monday": "every monday",
    "tuesday": "every tuesday",
    "wednesday": "every wednesday",
    "thursday": "every thursday",
    "friday": "every friday",
    "saturday": "every saturday",
    "sunday": "every sunday",
}


@dataclasses.dataclass()
class Record:
    user: int
    title: str
    date: Union[datetime.datetime, str]
    time: Union[datetime.datetime, str]
    type: Literal[
        "everyday", "few_times_a_day", "every_few_days", "week", "month", "year", "once"
    ]
    need_delete: bool
    id: Optional[int]

    def format_period(self) -> str:
        match self.type:
            case 'year':
                return f'every year {self.time}'
            case 'once':
                return self.date
            case 'week':
                return f'{days_of_week_dict[self.time]}'
            case 'month':
                return f'every month on {self.time}'
            case 'several_min':
                return f'every {self.time} minutes'
            case 'everyday':
                return f'everyday at {self.time}'
            case 'several_hours':
                return f'every {self.time} hours'
            case 'every_few_days':
                return f'every {self.time} days'
            case _:
                raise ValueError(f'Unknown record type: {self.type}')


def make_record_text(record: Record) -> str:
    return f"{record=}; {record.format_period()}"


print(
    make_record_text(
        Record(
            user=297850814,
            title="month",
            date="month",
            time="25",
            type="month",
            need_delete=False,
            id=1,
        )
    )
)
```

This outputs

```
record=Record(user=297850814, title='month', date='month', time='25', type='month', need_delete=False, id=1);
every month on 25
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue arises because:

1. Call to days_of_week_dict will be evaluated when creating `periods`
2. You used bracket notation with potentially non-existing dictionary keys

You can fix that by changing bracket notation to `.get()` dictionary method, which will evaluate as `None` if the key is non-existing (or other value if you specify).

So changing `periods` assignment to:

```
periods = {'year': f'every year {record.time}',
           'once': record.date,
           'week': f'{days_of_week_dict.get(record.time)}',
           'month': f'every month on {record.time}',
           'several_min': f'every {record.time} minutes',
           'everyday': f'everyday at {record.time}',
           'several_hours': f'every {record.time} hours',
           'every_few_days': f'every {record.time} days',
           }
```

Should fix the problem.